# Copy data from Linux console to Windows-host-clipboard using Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

I'm using Windows Terminal to access my Linux boxes and I have a need for copying data from the Linux console to the Windows host clipboard, it that possible?

More specific I run a .Net core application on Linux which need to copy a string to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the way, directly on the Linux console:

```bash
printf $'\e]52;c;%s\a' "$(base64 <<<'hello world')"
```

Now I just need to find a was to do the same in C#